# Sending POST data to HTTPS redirect PHP

Tags: php, post, curl, https

I need to redirect the current user to an external page (other domain) with some parameters that will be used on that page. To do that I'm using cURL, an example code is below:

```
  $postfields = array('key'=>'value');
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://domain.com/example.aspx');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // On dev server only!
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
```

But the user stays on the same page and I don't know if any data is transmitted.

What is the problem here? Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Well you will probably want to use a `header()` for the redirect.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); should be true

Comment: @Dagon Oh, yeah, duh. That's a good plan! I should brush up on my cURL!

Comment: thanks for your replies, I have set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION true but nothing happened. Do I need more configurations? or just use the header to the redirection? In case i need to use header(), how do I transmit the parameters?